# A lot of notify, but only one sound

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, notify

On my app i'm showing a lot of notice.
If user turn off device for some hour, when turn on, arrived a lot of notice.
there're a way to use the sound only 1 time, and not once for each notify?

Comment: How do you play this sound notice ? Isn't there a way to check if it's playing (the MediaPlayer for example, if you're using it) ?

Comment: You can set [this flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE)

Comment: Or you can use `collapse_key` parameter to collapse all pending messages into a one group (if you use GCM)

Comment: @g00dy i play the sound, with the notice.. notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

Comment: @esentsov thanks, it work with notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;

Answer (score 0):

Use FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE:

```
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```